# F# Overloaded Operator ( *= ) with floats not working with other floats

Tags: .net, f#, operator-overloading

I'm normalizing my vectors like this function:

```
member this.Normalize =
    if  this.Length > _zerotolerance  then
        let inv:float = 1.0 / this.Length 
        this.x <- this.x *= inv   // overloaded
        this.y <- this.y *= inv   // overloaded
```

However - a **Multiplication Assignment** operator   *=   for floats isn't available to me by default, so I needed to create one.

According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204%28v=vs.110%29 I have to overload operators in the following manner:

```
static member ( *= ) (arg1 : type, arg1: type) = ...code etc...
```

So I have the overloaded the following operators for multiplication assignment in my F# codefile like this:

```
// Operator
static member ( *= ) ( v1:vector2, v2:vector2 ) =
   v1.x <- v1.x + v1.x * v2.x 
   v1.y <- v1.y + v1.y * v2.y 

static member ( *= ) ( v1:vector2, v2:float )  = 
   v1.x <- v1.x + v1.x * v2
   v1.y <- v1.y + v1.y * v2 

// Operator
static member ( *= ) ( f1:float, f2:float ) = 
    f1 <- f1 + f1 * f2
```

And it doesn't seem to work. Even after overloading the operator I have the following problem:

> vector2.fs(107,36): error FS0001: The type 'float' does not support
>   any operators named '*='

So the operator *= is not working for floats. It is failing here ( normalize function ):

```
this.X <- this.X *= inv
```

To check the other overloads for the operator I temporarily created test functions for Vector2s:

```
member this.MultiplyAssignmentTest_1(v1:vector2,v2:vector2):vector2 = v1 *= v2

member this.MultiplyAssignmentTest_2(v1:vector2,v2:float):vector2 = v1 *= v2
```

The operator passed test for both **Vector *= Vector** and **Vector *= Float**  but continues to fail when I try to do **Float *= Float**

A 3rd test function - **float *= float**: fails entirely with the exact same error.

```
member this.MultiplyAssignmentTest_3(v1:float,v2:float):float = v1 *= v2
```

OFC I could always just write `this.X <- This.X + This.X *= inv`, thats fine for short formulas. But that isnt very economical when I start writing lots of vectored math with this - and for the sake of tring to code quickly.

1. What did I mess up? Did I really screw up my overloads somehow, or is there a bug somewere I don't know about?
2. Why does it work with my **Vector2 *= Float**  but not with **Float *= Float**?
3. Or maybe there's a typo/casing error I'm not noticing on my own?

Comment: for a start, the type signature will be wrong as if `f1` is a `float` you can't assign to it as `floats` are immutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John said, better avoid working with mutables.
The other problem is you want to overload the operator (*=) for float, but you don't have the definition of float Type, so you are trying to do it in the definition of your class and that overload will never execute since no parameters are of the type of the class (vector2).

The other two overloads work fine because at least one parameter involved in the overload is of the type (vector2) so they will resolve.

You can define (=*) at global level but then it would not work with vector2, so you need to specify in its definition at global level all overloads.

You can try this code which uses an independent class for the overloads:

```
type vector2 = {x:float; y:float} with

// Operator
    static member ( *= ) ( v1:vector2, v2:vector2 ) =
       {x = v1.x + v1.x * v2.x; y = v1.y + v1.y * v2.y }

    static member ( *= ) ( v1:vector2, v2:float )  = 
       {x = v1.x + v1.x * v2; y = v1.y + v1.y * v2 }

type Overloads = Overloads with
    static member (?<-) (a:vector2, Overloads, b:vector2) = a *= b
    static member (?<-) (a:vector2, Overloads, b:float)   = a *= b
    static member (?<-) (a:float  , Overloads, b:float)   = a *  b

let inline ( *= ) f1 f2 =  f1 ? (Overloads) <- f2

// now you can add more methods for vector2 using the global definition of ( *=)
type vector2 with 
    static member Length (v1:vector2) = sqrt( v1.x ** 2.0 + v1.y ** 2.0)
    // more methods
```

Doing this trick, you can use (*=) for both floats and vector2.
Also note, I removed the mutables.

Comment: OK. That looks good.  I was on my way to completly porting my Vector2 class from VB.Net (others probably to follow) as my first F# project (including the entire math library), were all of my Overloads, built in translation functions/routines and such were all one single class - while also making use of a shared math library. I was worried that I was going to lose some precision ( I need lots of precision ).        Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
let inline ( *= ) (p : byref<_>) x = p <- p * x

[<Literal>]
let _zerotolerance = 1e-3

type A(x0, y0) =
    let mutable x = x0
    let mutable y = y0

    member __.Length = sqrt (x * x + y * y)

    member this.Normalize =
        if this.Length > _zerotolerance  then
            let inv:float = 1.0 / this.Length 
            &x *= inv
            &y *= inv
```